# How to read data from a webpage in two instances (objects)?

Tags: php, curl

I'm working on this project:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init("https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html = curl_exec($curl);

if(!empty($curl)){
    $thispage = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $thispage->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors();

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($thispage);
    $status = $xpath->evaluate('string(//*[@id="p36"])');
    echo $status;


}
```

Curl connects to website `timeanddate.com` and reads data from object `//*[@id="p36"]` (xpath).

> How can I read data from two objects instead of just one?

Comment: What do you mean by "two objects"?

Comment: Two objects. I mean specific rows in website (e.g. time of city Accra is in row) are called by me as objects, which I mentioned as `//*[@id="p36"]`. I wanted curl to read those informations by xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found out that two variables are necessary:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($thispage);
$status = $xpath->evaluate('string(//*[@id="p36"])');   //first object
$xpath2 = new DOMXPath($thispage);
$status2 = $xpath2->evaluate('string(//*[@id="p28"])'); //second object
echo $status;
echo $status2;
```